# Free jqgrid don't reload data on Edges

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, free-jqgrid

I'm adding a jqGrid table in my page, where I need to add registers, after I do some processing I need to reload de data, all is local, no  server communication, this is my code:

```
$(function () {

    $.extend(true, $.jgrid.inlineEdit, {
        beforeCancelRow: function (options, rowid) {
            $(this).jqGrid('saveRow', rowid);
            $(this).setCell(rowid, 'TipoEtiqueta', '', '', { 'title': null });  
            return false;
        }
    });

    L_Grid.jqGrid({
        loadonce: false,
        data: notas,
        datatype: "local",
        refresh: true,
        colNames: ['Código Etiqueta', 'Tiempo (hh:mm:ss)', 'Descripción', 'Privada', 'Eliminar'],
        colModel: [
            {
                name: 'Codigo', index: 'Codigo', hidden: true, search: false
            },
            {
                name: 'TiempoMilisegundos', index: 'TiempoMilisegundos', align: "center", search: false,
                formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                    return TimeFormat(cellvalue)
                },
                cellattr: function (rowId, val) {
                    return 'aria-label="Tiempo de la etiqueta ' + TimeFormat(val) + '" title="Tiempo de la etiqueta" onclick="navegarEtiqueta(' + val + ')" tabindex="0"';
                }
            },
            {
                name: 'Descripcion', index: 'Descripcion', align: "center", width: 320, editable: true, editoptions: { required: false, maxlength: 255, "class": "descripcion-etiqueta", list: "etiquetasPredefinidas" }, classes: "descripcion-etiqueta",
                cellattr: function (rowId, val) {
                    return 'tabindex="0"';
                }
            },
            {
                name: 'TipoEtiqueta', index: 'TipoEtiqueta', align: "center", search: false, editable: true,
                formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                    var titulo = cellvalue ? "Privada": "Pública";
                    return '    <label class="switch" title="' + titulo +'">'
                        + '     <input tabindex="0" type="checkbox" ' + ValidarCheck(cellvalue) + ' aria-disabled="true" disabled aria-label="Indicador de etiqueta privada" role="switch">'
                        + '     <span class="slider round" tabindex="0" aria-label="Indicador de etiqueta privada ' + TipoEtiqueta(cellvalue) + '"></span>'
                        + ' </label>';
                },
                edittype: 'custom',
                editoptions: {
                    custom_element: function (value, options) {
                        var V_Localdata = L_Grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data');
                        var V_RowData = V_Localdata[L_Grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', '_index')[options.rowId]];

                        return $('<label class="switch">'
                            + ' <input tabindex="0" type="checkbox" ' + ValidarCheck(V_RowData.TipoEtiqueta) + ' aria-label="Indicador de etiqueta privada" role="switch">'
                            + '     <span class="slider round"></span>'
                            + '</label>');
                    },
                    custom_value: function (elem, operation, value) {
                        if (operation === 'get') {
                            return $(elem).find("input[type='checkbox']").is(':checked');
                        } else if (operation === 'set') {
                            $("input[type='checkbox']", elem).val(value);
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                name: "act", align: "center", search: false,
                formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                    return '<span onClick="eliminarEtiqueta.call(this)" contenteditable="false"><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm my-0 icono-borrar" aria-label="Eliminar etiqueta" title="Eliminar etiqueta" /></span>';
                }
            }
        ],
        onSelectRow: function (rowid, status, e) {
            var $self = $(this), savedRow = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "savedRow");

            if (savedRow.length > 0 && savedRow[0].id !== rowid) {
                $self.jqGrid('saveRow', savedRow[0].id);
                $self.setCell(savedRow[0].id, 'TipoEtiqueta', '', '', { 'title': null });
            }

            lastsel = rowid;
        },
        guiStyle: "bootstrap4",
        autowidth: true,
        shrinkToFit: true,
        height: 'auto',
        autoResizing: { compact: true },
        responsive: true,
        rownumbers: false,
        sortorder: "desc",
        altRows: true,
        ignoreCase: true,
        loadComplete: function (data) {
            $('#numerRegistros').html(L_Grid.getGridParam("records"));
        },
    });


    // cambia el tamaño del grid dinámicamente
    $(window).bind("resize", function () {
        L_Grid.jqGrid("setGridWidth", L_Grid.closest(".container").width());
    }).triggerHandler("resize");

    $("#txtBusqueda").on("input", function () {
        var savedRow = L_Grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "savedRow");

        if (savedRow.length > 0) {
            L_Grid.jqGrid('saveRow', savedRow[0].id);
            L_Grid.setCell(savedRow[0].id, 'TipoEtiqueta', '', '', { 'title': null });  
        }

        var postData = L_Grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "postData"),
            colModel = L_Grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel"),
            rules = [],
            searchText = $(this).val(),
            l = colModel.length,
            i,
            cm;
        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            cm = colModel[i];
            if (cm.search !== false && (cm.stype === undefined || cm.stype === "text")) {
                rules.push({
                    field: cm.name,
                    op: "cn",
                    data: searchText
                });
            }
        }
        postData.filters = JSON.stringify({
            groupOp: "OR",
            rules: rules
        });
        L_Grid.jqGrid("setGridParam", { search: true });
        L_Grid.trigger("reloadGrid", [{ page: 1, current: true }]);
        return false;

    });

    L_Grid.jqGrid('bindKeys', {
        onEnter: function (rowid) {

            L_Grid.jqGrid('editRow', rowid, true, null, null, null, {}, function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    L_Grid.focus();
                }, 100);
            });
        }
    });

});


function ReloadNotsGrid(nots) {

L_Grid.jqGrid('setGridParam',
    {
        datatype: 'local',
        data: nots
    })
    .trigger("reloadGrid");}
```

When I call `ReloadNotsGrid` I get this exception on Edges:

> jquery.jqgrid.min.js
>   0x800a13b5 - JavaScript runtime error: Assignment to read-only properties is not allowed in strict mode

Comment: Can you please inform us which version of the MS Edge browser you are using for making this test? We are not able to test the above posted JS code to reproduce the issue. I suggest you try to post the sample code that we can run with the MS Edge browser. It can help us to understand the issue in a better way. If you are explicitly running the code in a strict mode then I suggest you run the code in a normal mode that may help to fix this error.

Comment: Hi @ Deepak-MSFT Thank you for answering I found the solution, I was sending the data 'raw' as string, I needed to do `jQuery.parseJSON (notes)`, but the exception that I was getting was a little misleading. And other rare thing was that I only get this exception in MS Edges (Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.18363, Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0), in chrome (Version 81.0.4044.138 (Official Build) (64-bit)) it works well.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution to the issue. I suggest you post your solution as an answer for this thread and try to mark your own answer as an answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I was sending the data 'raw' as string, I needed to do `jQuery.parseJSON (notes)`, but the exception that I was getting was a little misleading. And other rare thing was that I only get this exception in MS Edges (Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.18363, Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0), in chrome (Version 81.0.4044.138 (Official Build) (64-bit)) it works well.

The code end up looking like this:

```
function ReloadNotsGrid(nots) {

var dataToLoad = jQuery.parseJSON(nots);

L_Grid.jqGrid('setGridParam',
    {
        datatype: 'local',
        data: dataToLoad
    })
    .trigger("reloadGrid");
}
```

Comment: You can use jsonstring as datatype parametrer and jqGrid will do the rest for you - i.e `datatype: 'jsonstring'` - read the docs for the valid datatypes.